# Android - EditText keyboard hides half of listview, even when the keyboard gets closed

Tags: android, android-listview, keyboard

So I have a listview with an edittext on top of it allowing the user to search for stuff in the listview. Unfortunately, I'm coming across a weird issue where upon opening the keyboard by clicking upon the EditText, the ListView shrinks to the screen that isn't blocked by the keyboard. This is fine, but when I close the keyboard, the ListView remains the same half-screen size and the space where the keyboard was is now totally blank and useless.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? It's causing me a lot of grief and I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/word_search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:hint="Enter a word you'd like to search"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/words_list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This fragment is contained in this viewpager layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:rippleColor="#33FFFFFF"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/save"/>



 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anybody have any clue what's happening? Ideally, I would like to make the ListView's size static so it does not get redrawn when the keyboard is pulled up, but I would accept the listview resizing back to normal when the keybaord is closed too.

Thanks!